# Powershell runs, visible on taskbar, but shows no window

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell

(Windows 10). When running powershell, it is visible on the taskbar and task view but when the icon is clicked or it is switched to using alt+tab, the window is not visible.

I tried running it using run and through cmd using the commands:

```
start powershell -WindowStyle Normal
start powershell
```

I also tried using the option in right click+start and right click+context menu and running the .exe file directly but I still get the same result.

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PClnE.gif)

EDIT: Preview - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFgMK.jpg

Comment: Did you try to use Win+Arrow keys to move the window?

Comment: @Seth yes i did. nothing happens.

Comment: Not an answer but a troubleshooting suggestion. [Open a command prompt](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/7-ways-launch-command-prompt-windows-7-windows-8) and don't use the **start** command. The use of **start** could be obfuscating a **PowerShell** startup error. In the command prompt's window just enter **PowerShell** and see what that tells you - if anything.

Comment: @ScottWelker it opens powershell inside the cmd window. This works, but I want to be able to open powershell in its own window,

Comment: 1. What's output from `where powershell`? 2. Could `start "" powershell` help?

Comment: You'll need clarify exactly what you mean by "its own window". Not sure what you're looking. 

I've gotten my hand slapped for (apparently improperly) trying to help. Doh! 
Best of luck. I am out.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I appreciate your admonition, especially regarding my first non-answer answer. My bad :-/

My second answer was an answer... just not what this poster meant to ask. Still I'll be more careful. I did truly believe I had answered the question.

Comment: @ScottWelker the window that shows when you normally run powershell.exe. My 'open powershell here' option shows the icon on the taskbar but I can't interact with the actual powershell window

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you seek. I suspect you may have a shortcut or some (windows) shell extension that launches with specific customizations that you are hoping to achieve. See whether the "thing" that provides the look you seek is a "short-cut" or try to identify the underlying shell extension. Then you can launch its target.

Comment: @ScottWelker Here: https://imgur.com/bF8ljKT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the taskbar shows a preview of the window, it probably exists somewhere. While you have the window active, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up the window’s system menu. Select “Move”, press any cursor key once. The window will then follow your mouse cursor. Press the mouse button to drop it.

/edit:
As mentioned in the comment, the system menu also allows access to the console window’s settings (like buffer size, colors, etc.), including the ability to set the window position.

Comment: it doesn't work. however, when I open properties and checked layout > window position > let system position window and then restarted powershell, it worked.

Comment: Great to hear it worked out! I updated my answer with the info from your comment.

Comment: In my case, move did not work. I selected "Maximize".